# CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available (using oauth2client in google app engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyopenssl, oauth2client, gspread

I am using gspread to connect my application to  spreadsheet and for that I am using the following code

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

json_key = json.load(open('service_account.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet = gc.open('Order Database').sheet1
```

This same code worked fine when I used it in idle to get access to the spreadsheet.But when I used it in the code for my application, for which I am using Google App Engine, when I run the app and try to get access to the page I get this error

```
ERROR    2015-09-14 08:49:44,263 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/mbp13inch/Documents/Workspace/ehscanteen/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    db = Database()
  File "/Users/mbp13inch/Documents/Workspace/ehscanteen/server.py", line 10, in __init__
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
  File "/Users/mbp13inch/Documents/Workspace/ehscanteen/lib/oauth2client/util.py", line 142, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mbp13inch/Documents/Workspace/ehscanteen/lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 1622, in __init__
    _RequireCryptoOrDie()
  File "/Users/mbp13inch/Documents/Workspace/ehscanteen/lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 1573, in _RequireCryptoOrDie
    raise CryptoUnavailableError('No crypto library available')
CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available
```

I even installed the libraries in the project directory successfully:

```
pip install -t lib PyOpenSSL
pip install -t lib gspread
pip install -t lib oauth2client
pip install -t lib cryptography
```

I even tried adding `--upgrade` to each of it and all of it installed successfully but got the same error

Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the error from the local appserver, or from the production environment? Or both? From the log i'm guessing it's local

Comment: If you make a test script, can you `import` the library manually?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I am using the google app engine app to run it locally.. and by library which ones are you talking about?

Comment: The one that it cannot find, crypto

Comment: if you are telling me to add this :  `from OpenSSL import crypto` i get an `ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl`

Comment: Installing pycrypto (pip install pycrypto) worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved the problem. All I actually had to was to add the following to `app.yaml` :

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "latest"
```